# php links added to code

Tags: php, html

This code is from view-source in Chrome:

```
<div class='pedSpouse'>Relation med <a class='familylink' file='157'     pers='24351162'><strong>KARL EMRIK Jakobsson</strong> f.    1897</div></div><div> <img id='pedMore' src='cmn/prg/pics/hpil.png'></div></div></div>
```

In inspect the img is embedded within a copy of the previous a tag:

```
<div><a class='familylink' file='157' pers='24351162'><img id='pedMore' src='cmn/prg/pics/hpil.png'></div>
```

The same thing occurs in two other places. 
With other data the code is as expected.

Same thing happens in Edge.
I have no idea where the extra code comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is broken.  Examine its structure:

```
<div class='pedSpouse'>
  Relation med 
  <a class='familylink' file='157' pers='24351162'>
    <strong>
      KARL EMRIK Jakobsson
    </strong>
    f. 1897
  <!-- You didn't close the "a" element -->
</div>
</div> <!-- You close a "div" element that was never opened -->
<div>
  <img id='pedMore' src='cmn/prg/pics/hpil.png'>
</div>
</div> <!-- You close a "div" element that was never opened -->
</div> <!-- You close a "div" element that was never opened -->
```

The rendered HTML is different from the page source because the page source is invalid and the browser is doing its best to make sense of it.  Use well-formed HTML for more control over how the HTML is interpreted by the browser.

**Hint:** When your HTML isn't doing what you expect, the *very first* step is to [validate it](https://validator.w3.org/).  The runtime behavior of invalid code is always undefined.

Comment: Thank You David. Of course You are right. After over 40 years programmning I should have seen that.